# Natbib does not accept 'und' instead of 'and' in *.bib

Tags: latex

Natbib (Overleaf) does not accept the german 'und' instead of 'and' in the *.bib.
The result is, that only one author is mentioned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

...

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Expose_Bib}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `and` in the `.bib` file is just a separator for multiple authors. If there are three authors, you have to write `<author1> and <author2> and <author3>`. It does not correspond to the separator used in the bibliography. What is used there is the responsibility of the `.bst` file. However, one should almost use past tense here, since nowadays most people use `biblatex` together with `biber`. This should give you the German key words automatically.